# Request Body in BigQuery

Tags: json, google-bigquery, insert-id

Good Day,

I am testing a post method in another system using BigQuery as its data source.
I am currently testing the call method on BigQuery's live data to see if the API request gets a response.

What I want to know is: is the `insertId` meant to be the column I want to target and, in this case, the Client ID and the JSON object should have all the data within that Column ID?

````
  "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest",
  "skipInvalidRows": false,
  "ignoreUnknownValues": false,
  "rows": [
    {
      "insertId": "ClientID",
      "json": {
        "ClientID": "55415",
        "Client": "LANGA BRANCH",
        "Project": "Customer Visits",
        "Developer": "Bryan",
        "Hours": "300"
      }
    }
  ]
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `insertId` is an optional field.  It can (and probably should) be omitted entirely, as it's used on a best effort basis for deduplication.  Omitting it yields higher throughput: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts_without_insertid_fields

The REST reference for insertAll is here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll